# Are there 8 bit ARM processors?

Tags: arm, processor

Is there anything below 32-bits for an ARM processor? I was wondering if there is or ever was an 8-bit ARM processor. I've searched but not seen any and so it seems that ARM processors are either 32 or 64 bits. Why is that?

I also noticed while writing this question, that the tag for ARM even says *32-bit microcontroller IP*.

Comment: Start where ARM comes from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acorn_Computers

Comment: Why should it *not* be like that? ARM wasn't created in the era where 8bit was state of the art.

Comment: No.  About the closest you could come would be implementing one in software running on an 8-bit core.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I figured as much, as I had never heard of or seen anything below 32-bits for ARM.

Comment: The smallest ARM processors today are Cortex-M0 and Cortex-M0+ (depending on configuration). With today's silicon process costs, a smaller processor has little scope for improvement at the system level.

Comment: @Chris Emulating ARM from a 8-bit core. Wow. That's hardcore (pun intended).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming "n bit" refers to the size of the general purpose registers all arm processors are 32 or 64 bit.

Prior to designing the ARM processor Acorn's computers had been designed around the mos technology 6502 and variants. They decided to leapfrog over the 16 bit generation and go straight to a 32-bit design. Instructions were 32 bits wide and so was the data path. Initially some bits were used as flag bits limiting addreses to 26-bit but these flags were later done away with allowing a fully 32-bit address space.

Acorn computers failed to maintain a viable position in the market but before that happened ARM had been spun off into a seperate company. ARM was a low power architecture and started to see a lot of use in mobile/embedded computing. Eventually as transistors got cheaper (in both cost and power terms) it worked it's way down into the microcontroller market.

Arm later introduced a mode called "Thumb" (sometimes reffered to as "Thumb1") where the instructions were only 16 bits wide. The registers however remained 32 bit. Thumb in it's original form was an incomplete instruction set, certain important operations could only be performed by switching back to Arm mode.

Even more recently arm introduced "Thumb2". This extended Thumb to produce a complete instruction set using a mixture of 16-bit and 32-bit instructions. Again the data registeres remained 32-bit. Modern ARM microcontrollers only support Thumb2 mode (sometimes with only a subset of the full "thumb2" instruction set), not traditional arm mode.

Comment: Don't forget Thumb mode. Some (all?) ARM micros support a mode where they switch to using 16 bit instructions. This can be a performance hit but normally results in a reduction in code size and RAM usage for systems that are very resource limited.

Comment: Thumb1 is an incomplete instruction set using 16-bit instructions, you have to switch to arm mode to do some stuff. Thumb2 is a mixed-width instruction set with some instructions 16 bit (same as thumb1) and others are 32-bit. General purpose registers remain 32-bit in thumb modes. Modern arm microcontrollers (cortex M) are thumb2 only.

Comment: I actually knew the bit about Acorn computers creating the first ARM, but you hit the point I was looking for. Even though the ARM was developed a while back, *They decided to leapfrog over the 16 bit generation and go straight to 32-bit design.* Thanks.

Comment: @PeterGreen: The Cortex-M3 parts always operate in Thumb mode, but with the aforementioned two-word "Thumb2" extended opcodes and a conditional prefix that can support almost all 32-bit ARM instructions.  The Cortex-M0 parts always operate in Thumb mode, but with very few added instructions.  The instruction set may be "incomplete", but it's what the Cortex-M0 has to work with.

Comment: The M0 indeed only has a handful of 32-bit instructions but those that it does have make the difference between an instruction set you can use to write most but not all of your system and an instruction set you can use to write all of your system.

Answer (score 8):

Nope.

ARM was a 32-bit architecture from the day it was introduced by Acorn...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#Acorn_RISC_Machine:_ARM2